# Сбрасывается запрет на изменение пароля пользователя в домене Active Directory

Tags: windows, active-directory

В подчиненном домене при установке в свойствах учетной записи пользователя "Запретить смену пароля пользователем" примерно через 25-30 минут эта галочка снова отключается.

Не могу понять по какой причине. Может кто в курсе?

Возможно какая та групповая политика работает, вроде все пересмотрел так и не нашел.

Comment: может все много проще: админстраторы нижнего домена без согласования меняют опцию запрета, считая данное поведение сбоем?